# Animate an image or a view along the curved path created using 'Path' imported from "react-native-svg"

Tags: react-native, animation, mobile-development

I need to create a page to show the progress of an user for a program based on the milestones. To achieve that a curve path is created using 'Path' imported from "react-native-svg" and now progress icon should animate/move along the path.

[here is the actual requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Qa2.png)

The red marker should move along the curve to some particular point based on his/her progress in the program.

**NOTE - I already have created the path. All I need is animation of the marker**

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem and utilizes both geometry and dynamic rendering techniques. We can leverage the capabilities of `SVG` or React Native's vector drawing libraries, and we can dynamically calculate the position of the progress icon along a curved path based on a given `progress percentage`.

Implementation in `React-native`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Path, Svg, Circle, G } from 'react-native-svg';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';

const ProgressPath = ({ progress }) => {
  const [progressPosition, setProgressPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const ref = useRef(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    if(!ref.current) return;

    const path = ref.current;
    const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
    const position = path.getPointAtLength(pathLength * progress);
    setProgressPosition({ x: position.x, y: position.y });
  }, [progress]);

  return (
    <Svg width="400" height="500">
      {/* Path */}
      <Path
        ref={ref}
        id="curve"
        fill="none"
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="6"
        d="M 200,50
           C 250,100 150,100 200,150
           C 250,200 150,200 200,250
           C 250,300 150,300 200,350
           C 250,400 150,400 200,450"
      />

      {/* Marker */}
      <Circle
        cx={progressPosition.x}
        cy={progressPosition.y}
        r="5"
        fill="red"
      />
    </Svg>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0.5);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{`Progress: ${Math.floor(progress * 100)}%`}</Text>
      <ProgressPath progress={progress} />
      <Button 
        title="Decrease Progress"
        onPress={() => setProgress((prev) => prev - 0.1)} 
      />
      <Button 
        title="Increase Progress"
        onPress={() => setProgress((prev) => prev + 0.1)} 
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### **React:**

Also, I created in `React` as well. The only major change is using `document.getElementById` instead of `ref`. Here is the implementation:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ProgressPath = ({ progress }) => {
  const [progressPosition, setProgressPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const path = document.getElementById("curve");
    const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
    const position = path.getPointAtLength(pathLength * progress);
    setProgressPosition({ x: position.x, y: position.y });
  }, [progress]);

  return (
    <svg width="1000" height="500">
      {/* Path */}
      <path
        id="curve"
        fill="none"
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="6"
        d="
           M 200,50
           C 250,100 150,100 200,150
           C 250,200 150,200 200,250
           C 250,300 150,300 200,350
           C 250,400 150,400 200,450
         "
      />

      {/* Marker */}
      <circle
        cx={progressPosition.x}
        cy={progressPosition.y}
        r="5"
        fill="red"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0.5);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`Progress: ${Math.floor(progress * 100)}%`}</h1>
      <ProgressPath progress={progress} />
      <button onClick={() => setProgress((prev) => prev - 0.1)}>
        Descrease Progress
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setProgress((prev) => prev + 0.1)}>
        Increase Progress
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Making the animation smooth:

We can achieve smooth animation by gradually increasing/descreasing the movement by **0.1%** within a period of small time intervals(e.g. **50ms**). Here is the implementation for the same:

**Storing previous progress:**

```js
const App = () => {
  const [prevProgress, setPrevProgress] = useState(0.5);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0.5);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`Progress: ${Math.floor(progress * 100)}%`}</h1>
      <ProgressPath prevProgress={prevProgress} progress={progress} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPrevProgress(progress);
          setProgress((prev) => prev - 0.1);
        }}
      >
        Descrease Progress
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPrevProgress(progress);
          setProgress((prev) => prev + 0.1);
        }}
      >
        Increase Progress
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Defining the interval:**

```js
const interval_in_ms = 50;
```

**Progress Path:**

```js
const ProgressPath = ({ prevProgress, progress }) => {
  const [progressPosition, setProgressPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  //This will make the position change gradually depending on the value of `interval_in_ms`.
  function animatePositionChange(
    path,
    prevProgress,
    progress,
    setProgressPosition
  ) {
    const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

    var partialProgress = prevProgress;
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (prevProgress < progress) {
        if (partialProgress > progress) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        partialProgress += 0.01;
      } else {
        if (partialProgress < progress) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        partialProgress -= 0.01;
      }

      const position = path.getPointAtLength(pathLength * partialProgress);
      setProgressPosition({ x: position.x, y: position.y });
    }, interval_in_ms);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const path = document.getElementById("curve");
    animatePositionChange(path, prevProgress, progress, setProgressPosition);
  }, [progress]);

  return (
    <svg width="1000" height="500">
      {/* Path */}
      <path
        id="curve"
        fill="none"
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="6"
        d="
           M 200,50
           C 250,100 150,100 200,150
           C 250,200 150,200 200,250
           C 250,300 150,300 200,350
           C 250,400 150,400 200,450
         "
      />

      {/* Marker */}
      <circle
        style={{
          transition: `all ${interval_in_ms}ms linear`,
          willChange: "cx, cy",
        }}
        cx={progressPosition.x}
        cy={progressPosition.y}
        r="5"
        fill="red"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Note:

- `transition: all ${interval_in_ms}ms linear`
  This is responsible for a smooth transition
- `willChange: cx, cy`;
  The [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) CSS property hints to browsers how an element is expected to change. Browsers may set up optimizations before an element is actually changed.

Comment: Thanks for the time and efforts. I tried this one but the marker is just jumping between two coordinates only. I need a smooth animation on the curve.

Comment: @vinuChan Added the animation functionality. Let me know if this is what you are looking for. Also, You can customize it by changing the variables accordingly